# Calculate sum of row based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a df

```
data = [[1, 10], [1, 5], [1, 4], [0, 3], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 5], [2, 8], [4, 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['no', 'count'])
```

which prints values as,

```
no  count
1    10   
1    5
1    4
0    3
0    3
1    2
1    1
1    5
2    8
4    9
```

- I want to get the first "count" when "no" become 1 (consider as value 1)
- When the number will be "not 1", get that "count" (consider as value 2)
- subtract value2 - value1
- start next value when again "no" become 1.
- finally, calculate the sum

Expected output:
(10-3) = 7
and
(2-8) = -6

```
7
-6
```

and sum is,

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
>>> vals = df.groupby(df.no.eq(1).diff().ne(0).cumsum())["count"].first()
>>> result = (vals * (-1) ** np.arange(len(vals))).sum()
>>> result
1
```

where we first groupby the consecutive groups over they are 1 or not and take the first values therein. Then to put an alternating sign to the values, we use `(-1)`'s power over `0..N-1`. Then we sum the multiplication.

`vals` are this by the way:

```
1    10
2     3
3     2
4     8
```

---

Alternative without multiplying by -1's powers:

```
vals = df.groupby(df.no.eq(1).diff().ne(0).cumsum())["count"].first().to_numpy()

result = (vals[::2] - vals[1::2]).sum()
```

where we subtract the odd-indexed values from even-indexed values.

---

Another alternative based on `itertools.groupby` with 1 pass over data:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

iterable = enumerate(groupby(zip(df["no"].eq(1), df["count"]), key=itemgetter(0)))

result = sum((1-2*(j&1)) * next(gr)[1] for j, (_, gr) in iterable)
```

which does the sign determination on the fly with enumeration and `j`'s  parity. But not as readable.

Comment: Updated the question a bit, can you please check

Comment: @sam Edited the answer, groupby changed a bit (in fact, simplified). hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with groupby `df['no'].eq(1)` (`m`) and `m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()`:

```
m = df['no'].eq(1)
g = (
    df.groupby([m, m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()])['count'].first()
)
```

```
no     no
False  2      3
       4      8
True   1     10
       3      2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Then subtract the `True` no from the `False` no:

```
g.loc[True].values - g.loc[False].values
```

```
[ 7 -6]
```

and `sum`:

```
(g.loc[True].values - g.loc[False].values).sum()
```

```
1
```

Comment: Updated to mask where m is `1` instead of 'no` directly @sam